# Creating a centre dotted line in HTML

Tags: html, svg, html5-canvas

I'm working on a pong game and currently, for a design, I'm trying to create a vertical dotted line on the centre of the canvas but I couldn't figure out how is it possible to do so in HTML.[image]

the HTML code I currently have is

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        @import url(style.css);
        p.highlight {
            color: red;
        }
        svg {
            background-color: rgb(41, 41, 36);
        }
    </style>
    <script src="svgelement.js"></script>
    <script src="observable.js"></script>
    <script src="pong.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Pong</h1>
    <svg id="canvas" width="600" height="600"/>

</body>
```

Would appreciate some help on this.

Comment: Using html on a canvas...? You'll need JavaScript to modify the canvas. MDN has a perfect example on how to draw a dotted line on a canvas using JavaScript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setLineDash).

Comment: Despite the svg tag, I assume you want to draw the line using Javascript? If that's the case you need to replace the svg tag with something like `<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600" />`.

Comment: By the way, in my youth I had a pong console from Philips, which at that time was a real miracle. I loved the sliders. http://www.pugo.org/collection/console/86/

Comment: I think that all the drawing takes place in JavaScript, maybe in pong.js? can you share that code?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you will like this, but i would suggest, changing the svg tag, and make it simple, using box model or box shapes with easy CSS. It will look a little something like this:

```css
.box {
  height: 500px;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 280px;
  bottom: 50px;
}

.pong1 {
  height: 80px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: grey;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  bottom: 300px;
}

.pong2 {
  height: 80px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: grey;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  right: 300px;
  bottom: 300px;
}

.border:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 425px;
  bottom: 294px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 36.7%;
  border-bottom: 3px dotted white;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="pong1"></div>
<div class="pong2"></div>
<div class="border"></div>
```

I know it looks clumsy and is not perfect, but it works, and it's simple,
Thank you.